# SharePoint API getfilebyserverrelativeurl saying doesn't exist

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a sharepoint site, let's say `http://sharepoint.company.com`
I'm trying to pull data from `sharepoint.company.com/sites/one/sales/retail_locations.aspx`

when I perform a get request on

```
http://sharepoint.company.com/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('/sites/one/sales/retail_locations.aspx')
```

It keeps returning "The file /sites/one/sales/retail_locations.aspx does not exist"

I'm literally looking at the site in my other tab. It's driving me insane. Anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a file at web level and your targeting site collection. So if you try to target the web level "`/sites/one/sales`" instead of site collection level "`http://sharepoint.company.com`" it would work.

the call to would be

```
http://sharepoint.company.com/sites/one/sales/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath('/sites/one/sales/retail_locations.aspx')
```

Is there any particular reason to hit site collection level instead of web level.

All the best!!!

Comment: hmm... When I do this I simply get a 404

Comment: Where is this file? In which document library?

Comment: Hi, Modify rest call as http://sharepoint.company.com/sites/one/sales/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath('/sites/one/sales/retail_locations.aspx')